# Django restframework search function doesn't return the desired output?

Tags: django, search, model

I want to use Django search feature while trying to implement it. The implemented code doesn't work

View.py file

```
class SearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = BlogDetails.objects.all()
    search_fields = ["blog_title"]
    filter_backend = [filters.SearchFilter]
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer
```

Serializer.py

```
class SearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogDetails
        fields = ("blog_title","blog_author")
```

So I made a request like this

```
localhost:8000/search/search-blog/?search=jane
```

The Database I use is PostgreSQL

But it displays all the blogs that are in database and not the result which has jane in its title and I have added `django-filters` in `INSTALLED_APPS` But still it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

The `filters.SearchFilter` comes from DRF, not `django-filers`. Did you configure filters backend globally to `django-filters`? I'm not sure ATM, but it might be a possible cause for this.

The example you've provided should work correctly without `django-filters` at all.

Try to remove `django-filters` from `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS`. If not possible, try to override `filter_backends = []` on this view.

Comment: Yeah I have configured django-filters and used it in settings and the mistake I made was that I missed a `s` in `filter_backend` it should be `filter_backends`. Anyways, Thanks for your time and help